# NeoVim: Broken Syntax Highlighting after heredoc "lua << EOF" in VimScript

Tags: syntax-highlighting, neovim

I'm facing the problem that my `init.vim` becomes not highlighted properly after the line with `lua << EOF` in NeoVim. The weird behaviour is 1) paired brackets are colored differently; 2) After `lua << EOF` a Lua context does begin, yet it doesn't seem to be ended after the next `EOF`, instead it continues being highlighted in a Lua syntax (all lines later on are affected). From the screenshot below you can see that the brackets in line 59 are displayed as white and red separately, and the Lua syntax stays after line 60.

[image]

The code itself is assumed as okay, since it can be sourced without any error or warning, and the editing functions normally. It should namly only be a problem with the highlighting.

Sadly I can't tell the context of this problem. I first noticed it today without doing anything special (e.g. installing a new plugin) and I'm not sure when it occured. I have no clue what is causing this, even after doing research on Google for more than one hour - I haven't seen any post describing a similar situation.

The problem remains with the default color scheme.

I was guessing the CoC extension `coc-vimlsp` could be relevant, but the problem remains after I disabled it. Otherwise I can't remember any NeoVim plugin that could have something to do with the highlighting.

EDIT: I noticed that the broken highlighting after `EOF` is relevant to the broken brackets. If I write no brackets in the heredoc block, the highlighting will work correctly. Looks like the Lua highlighting remains after the heredoc block **because** it thinks the brackets aren't closed properly. And this is only about round brackets `()`, other brackets like `[] {} ""` would cause no problem.

My `init.vim`:

```
" Indentation
set shiftwidth=4
set ai 
set si

" Show line numbers
set nu

" Show command at the bottom right of the screen
set sc

" Limit the number of items shown in popup
set ph=20

" Set the minimal number of lines below the cursor
set so=15

" Disable auto comment insertion
au Filetype * setlocal fo-=c fo-=o fo-=r

" vim-plug config
call plug#begin()
    " Themes
    Plug 'catppuccin/nvim', {'as': 'catppuccin'}
    Plug 'tiagovla/tokyodark.nvim'

    " Icon support
    Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'

    " Statusbar
    Plug 'nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim'

    " Fish support
    Plug 'dag/vim-fish'

    " Makrdown support
    Plug 'preservim/vim-markdown'

    " Markdown preview
    Plug 'iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim', { 'for': ['markdown', 'vim-plug'] }

    " TeX support
    Plug 'lervag/vimtex'

    " Auto close XML-like tags
    Plug 'alvan/vim-closetag'

    " Auto close brackets
    Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
    
    " CoC completion engine
    Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', { 'branch': 'release' }
call plug#end()

" catppuccin config
let g:catppuccin_flavour = "mocha" " latte, frappe, macchiato, mocha

lua << EOF
require("catppuccin").setup()
EOF

" Set colorscheme
colorscheme catppuccin

" lualine config
lua << EOF
require('lualine').setup({
    options = {
    theme = "horizon"
    }
})
EOF

" vim-markdown config
let g:tex_conceal = ""
let g:vim_markdown_math = 1
let g:vim_markdown_folding_disabled = 1
let g:vim_markdown_frontmatter = 1
let g:vim_markdown_new_list_item_indent = 0

" Enable vimtex for Markdown files
" Not ideal, since this enables ALL features of vimtex
au Filetype md,markdown call vimtex#init()

" VimTeX config
let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {'continuous': 0}

" CoC config
exe 'so ~/.config/nvim/coc_config.vim'
```

---

Operating system: MacOS Monterey 12.4

Output of `nvim -v`:

```
NVIM v0.8.0
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compiled by brew@Monterey

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ...
```

Comment: Could you share the output of `nvim --version`?

Comment: @SpenserBlack Ah, I forgot to mention the versions. Please check the edit.

Comment: were you able to figure the cause? I have an exact same issue.

Comment: @merrydeath Unfortunately I haven't found any solution yet. But recently I have migrated my config from Vim script to Lua, as suggested by my classmate and many people on the Internet, also taking advantage of NeoVim. So for me this problem is kinda avoided though not really solved.

Comment: Same problem here. Is there issue on NeoVim GitHub repository? I hope anyone knows...

Comment: I found GitHub Issue: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/20456

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue raised in both of Neovim and Vim repository.

Neovim side: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/20456

Vim side: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/11277

Workaround from the comment: reverting to v0.7.2 lua syntax:

```
curl -sS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neovim/neovim/v0.7.2/runtime/syntax/lua.vim > $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/lua.vim
```

Comment: I migrated from Vim to Lua but just now I tested this workaround, turned out reverting to 0.7.2 lua syntax works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Embedded syntax highlighting is enabled via [`g:vimsyn_embed`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/syntax.html#g%3Avimsyn_embed).

You need to enable

```
  " Heredoc highlighting
  let g:vimsyn_embed = 'lPr'  " support embedded lua, python and ruby
```

Plugin for additional heredoc highlighting: https://github.com/acarapetis/vim-sh-heredoc-highlighting